# Making a Matrix with Entries that are Arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Here is the problem:

I have 3 states (vectors in 3D), that I would like to pair up (e.g. (**a**,**a**), (**a**,**b**), (**a**,**c**), (**b**,**a**), (**b**,**b**), ...) into elements of a 3X3 matrix.

In a more abstract way, I have a set of 3 arrays with 3 entries, and I would like to produce a 3x3 array where the entries themselves are an array of 2 of the original arrays. (A lot of nesting).

For the 3 cartesian basis vectors this would look like:
**a** = (1,0,0), **b** = (0,1,0), **c** = (0,0,1)

and the matrix would be:

```
M = | {(1,0,0),(1,0,0)} {(1,0,0),(0,1,0)} {(1,0,0),(0,0,1)} |
    | {(0,1,0),(1,0,0)} {(0,1,0),(0,1,0)} {(0,1,0),(0,0,1)} |
    | {(0,0,1),(1,0,0)} {(0,0,1),(0,1,0)} {(0,0,1),(0,0,1)} |

# I appreciate I have formatted the matrix in code rather than LaTeX
# but I can't find the functionality to do this on StackOverflow
```

so the matrix has elements that are arrays of 2 entries, and the entries of those arrays are my 3D vectors (arrays with 3 entries).

The code that I am using to try to implement this is:

```
import numpy as np

a= np.array([0,0,0])
b= np.array([0,0,1])
c= np.array([0,2,0])

states = np.array([a,b,c])
def cycler(states):
    matrix = np.zeros((3,3))
    
    for x in range(0,3):
        for y in range(0,3):
            matrix[x,y]= np.array([states[x],states[y] ])

    return matrix

cycler(states)
```

However, when I run this code, I am getting an error on the line:

```
matrix[x,y]= np.array([states[x],states[y] ])
```

with the error message:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

As a bit of python newbie I'd really appreciate a bit of help to allow me to create the matrix of pairs of vectors!
(For context, my state vectors **a**, **b**, **c** are not the basis vectors, and I will then later be writing a function that will read the elements of the matrix, using the array of the 2 3D states in a further calculation.)

Comment: self explanatory "setting an array element with a sequence."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `matrix = np.zeros((3,3),dtype=object)` resolves your problem, though I would recommend you rather use a 4d-array of dimensions 3x3x2x3.